# How to use BeautifulSoup4 to scrape information from customer tags

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use/learn beautifulsoup4 to scrape some basic data from a website, specifically the information contained within the html record below:

```
<li class="is-first-in-list css-9999999" data-testid="record-999999999">
```

I have around 285,000 records all with a unique

```
data-testid
```

However, while I can obtain the information from classes and tags I am familar with, custom tags are still evading me.

I've tried variations of:

```
for link in soup.find_all("data-testid"):
    print() #changed to include data-testid.text/innertext/leftblank etc etc
```

The remainder of my code appears to work, as I can extract  tags and href data without issue (including printing these in the terminal), just nothing from custom tags, I'm user the solution is mindbogglingly simple, I've just failed to come up with a success yet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is this what you are trying to do?*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<li class="is-first-in-list css-9999999" data-testid="record-999999999">"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features='html.parser')
for link in soup.select("li"):
    print(link.get('data-testid'))
```

---

*Prints*

> ```
> record-999999999
> ```

---

*With class select*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<li class="is-first-in-list css-9999999" data-testid="record-999999999">
<li class="hello css-9999999" data-testid="record-8888888">
<li class="0mr3 css-9999999" data-testid="record-777777">"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features='html.parser')
for link in soup.select("li.is-first-in-list"):
    print(link.get('data-testid'))
```

---

*Prints*

> ```
> record-999999999
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @0m3r but with a few tweaks

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree

html = """<li class="is-first-in-list css-9999999" data-testid="record-999999999">"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features='lxml')
for link in soup.find_all("li", class_="is-first-in-list css-9999999"):
    print(link.get('data-testid'))
```

Generally, I find lxml is a lot faster than html.parser.

> That said, there are things you can do to speed up Beautiful Soup. If you’re not using lxml as the underlying parser, my advice is to start. Beautiful Soup parses documents significantly faster using lxml than using html.parser or html5lib.

from https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/, especially knowing that you have 285,000 elements to loop through. Also, the `class_` argument gives you more restrictions on the class so your not sifting through every `li` element.

Comment: Unfortunately not, when run on a live instance, its displaying every "li" despite the selection / filtering to the class.

Comment: @Realitybites can you send the website you're scrping?

Comment: unfortunately its an internal website at my office :(

Comment: Can you send a simplified version of what you're trying to scrape with a similar structure? @Realitybites